# Proving that $g(1) = 1$, where $g$ is a multiplicative arithmetic function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

I'm having some trouble understanding a simple problem about an arithmetic function. The problem is simply to answer true or false that

> *$g(1) = 1$*, assuming *$g$* is multiplicative and $g(n)$ $\neq 0$ for any $n$.

My work:

Since $g$ is multiplicative,

$$g(a\cdot1) = g(a)g(1)$$

$$g(a) \quad\,= g(a)g(1)$$

$$1 \;\,\, = g(1)$$

So $g(1)=1$ is a true statement.

I suspect I have oversimplified the problem, but I cannot yet understand how.

Comment: Taking $a=1$ is enough. You should mention, that you have cancelled by $g(a)\neq 0$.

Comment: $g(1)=1$ is part of the definition of $g$ being multiplicative, to me. This is a strange question.

Comment: @nicomezi Some (many) authors define $g$ as multiplicative if it satisfies "$(m,n) = 1 \implies g(mn) = g(m)g(n)$", thus considering the zero function multiplicative.

Answer (score 3):

$g(1)\cdot g(1)=g(1\cdot 1)=g(1)$. Since $g(1)\not =0$ we can say $g(1)=1$.

Comment: I think (well, I'm *very* close to being sure) the "$g(n) \neq 0$ for any $n$" in the question was meant as $(\exists n)(g(n)\neq 0)$. One more instance that shows "any" is a dangerous word.

Comment: it could be a $\forall n$

Answer (score 1):

In fact as long as there is at least one value $n_0$ for which $g(n_0)\ne 0$, we have $g(1)=1$.

(By the same argument: $g(n_0)=g(n_0\cdot 1)=g(n_0)\cdot g(1)$.
So $g(1)=1$.